# Area of the region given in polar coordinates as $\sec\theta\le r\le 2\cos\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have to verify a point:

I'm supposed to find the area of the region given in polar coordinates

$$\sec{\theta}\le r\le 2\cos{\theta}$$

I plotted the curves of $\sec{\theta}$ and $2\cos{\theta}$ between $-{\pi/4}$ and ${\pi/4}$

This gave me an indication that the region mentioned at the start comes from taking the area of $\sec{\theta}$ from $2\cos{\theta}$ but what I don't understand is how I can verify that $r$ is greater than or equal to $\sec{\theta}$, as was mentioned at the start.

Comment: Hey there, you might want to look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how MathJax works correctly. I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Notice that $r=\sec\theta$ is the line $x=1$, and that between $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ the circle $r=2\cos\theta$ is farther away from the origin than the line $x=1$, so the region you want is bounded on the inside by the line and on the outside by the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Since $r$ is allowed to vary between $\sec\theta$ and $2\cos\theta$, the polar area would look like
$$B' = \int_A \int_{\sec\theta}^{2\cos\theta} 1 \mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta$$
Where $A$ is the set $\{\theta \in (-\pi,\pi) : \sec\theta \le 2\cos\theta \}$
Now note that the transformation from carthesian coordinates to polar coordinates has determinant of $r$, so the true area is given by
$$B = \int_A \int_{\sec\theta}^{2\cos\theta} r \mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta$$
I'm sure you can evaluate the inner integral; for the outer integral you might ask a new question once you found $A$.